# generic captures from same instance cannot be inferred equal

Tags: java, generics, jackson

I have the following scenario:

```
public interface BaseConfig {
}

public abstract class BaseWidget<C extends BaseConfig> {
    public abstract C getConfig();
    public abstract void setConfig(C config);
    public abstract Class<C> getConfigClass();
}

public class ConcreteConfig implements BaseConfig {
    public String foo = "bar";
}

public class ConcreteWidget extends BaseWidget<ConcreteConfig> {
    private ConcreteConfig config;

    public ConcreteWidget(ConcreteConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    @Override
    public ConcreteConfig getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    @Override
    public void setConfig(ConcreteConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<ConcreteConfig> getConfigClass() {
        return ConcreteConfig.class;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to generically serialize and deserialize instances of `BaseConfig` into the correct type specified by implementations of `BaseWidget`. The following works:

```
final BaseWidget<ConcreteConfig> instance = new ConcreteWidget(new ConcreteConfig());
final BaseConfig config = instance.getConfig();
final String configJson = om.writeValueAsString(config);

instance.setConfig(om.readValue(configJson, instance.getConfigClass()));
```

Now if I try to make the above code generic (eliminate the occurance of `ConcreteConfig`, so the first line has the type `BaseWidget<? extends BaseConfig>`), I get the following compilation error on the last line:

> Error:(18, 40) java: incompatible types: BaseConfig cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends BaseConfig

or in IntelliJ:

> setConfig (capture<? extends BaseConfig>) in BaseWidget cannot be applied to (capture<? extends BaseConfig>)

I understand that the error tells me the two captures are incompatible, but why is that? To my understanding the type of `instance.setConfig(C)` and `instance.getConfigClass() -> Class<C>` must result in the same `C` because they come from the same instance.

I could work around this problem by giving `BaseWidget` a different method instead of `setConfig` like this.

```
public abstract void readConfig(ObjectMapper mapper, String rawConfig) throws IOException;
```

and implement it like this in `ConcreteWidget`:

```
@Override
public void readConfig(ObjectMapper mapper, String rawConfig) throws IOException {
    this.config = mapper.readValue(rawConfig, ConcreteConfig.class);
}
```

but I'd rather not have the widget depend on any serialization logic.

Here's my test maven project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=16zt2FC8Gs5Cke-kbYBDRhmytE5utVn8E

Comment: The error being reported by the compiler is indeed helpful. It prevents unsafe operations (as you would technically be able to call `instance.setConfig(instanceOfAnIncompatibleSubclassOfBaseConfig)`. If `ConcreteWidget` cannot take a different type of config (other than `ConcreteConfig`, then your only option is to use `BaseWidget<ConcreteConfig>`... or use raw types...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convince the compiler that both types `C` are the same, I needed to introduce a typename for the above operation. In my case extracting the code into a method like this did the trick:

```
private static <C extends BaseConfig> void parseSetConfig(BaseWidget<C> instance, String configJson) throws IOException {
    final C config = om.readValue(configJson, instance.getConfigClass());
    instance.setConfig(config);
}
```

This method can be called with the wildcard'ed `BaseWidget<? extends BaseConfig>` just fine:

```
final BaseWidget<? extends BaseConfig> instance = new ConcreteWidget(new ConcreteConfig());
final BaseConfig config = instance.getConfig();
final String configJson = om.writeValueAsString(config);

parseSetConfig(instance, configJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another work around would be as follow:

```
final BaseWidget<ConcreteConfig> instance = new ConcreteWidget(new ConcreteConfig());
```

Comment: That is exactly what I posted as an example of what I want to avoid. It cannot be strictly coupled to a specific implementation of `BaseConfig`